# IE8 Media queries with respond.js works on localhost not on server

Tags: internet-explorer-8, media-queries, ie8-compatibility-mode, respond.js

I'm trying to add media queries support to IE8 and as stated in the title, respond.js is working on my local machine but not on the server.

- I have the respond.js on the head, after the link to the CSS.
- The media queries are screen and (max-width: 940px){}
- the respond.js is being served by my server, so no x-domain issues.
- If I disable the CSS on IE8 all the site content is shown.
- I'm using grunt to output my live files and they are being minified, css, html and js.
- Already uploaded unminified version of HTML and CSS but no luck.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: already uploaded unminified js?

Comment: all but angular which seems to be working but it is worth the try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the respond.js on the head, after the link to the CSS.

You should place `respond.js` after any inline-CSS as well. A good place to put it would be at the end of `body` (or just before the closing `html` tag)

Comment: Moving it to the end of the file solved it. Thank you!

Comment: Wasted 2 Hours of my life on this... Thank you!